# Java create variable if it doesn't exist?

Tags: java

I'm trying to set an Array only if it doesn't exist but I cannot figure out how to do it since I get an error saying it doesn't exist:

```
if (null == arr) { // arr cannot be resolved to a variable
    arr = new ArrayList<task>();
}
```

Isn't there something such as `isset()` from `php`? Also what does `<>` hold?

Comment: where do you declared variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can not. `Java` is the language with strong static typing. There isn't any `isset` like in `JS`.

The only way is to `declare` your variable `arr` **before** and assign `null` value to it.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, since you're initializing `arr` as an `ArrayList` type, I will assume you have already declared the type of `arr` as `ArrayList<task>` or `List<Task>`.

If `arr` has not been initialized, it will produce an error if you attempt to compare it. Thus, you must initialize `arr` to null:

```
List<task> arr = null;
```

This way, when you run your code, you can simply use the expression:

```
if(arr == null)
    arr = new ArrayList<task>();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Task> arr=null;
if (null == arr) { // arr cannot be resolved to a variable
     arr = new ArrayList<task>();
}
```

it wiill work fine